# Conditions for equal composite functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx + d$.
On what conditions of a, b, c and d are:
$$f\circ g = g \circ  f\quad ?$$

Answer (score 1):

From given conditions:
$a(cx+d)+b = c(ax+b)+d$ => $(ac)x+ad+b=(ca)x+cb+d$ 
Comparing coefficients of x and 1, we get the condition 
$d(a-1) = b(c-1)$